# is there a way to generate a .o file for Geany?

Tags: assembly, arm, geany

I am getting the following error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Assignment_1.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Assignment_1.o'
clang: error: no input files
Compilation failed.
```

This is the code that is being used for execution:

```
as -g -mfpu=vfpv4 -o -alh Assignment_1.o Assignment_1.s>Assignment_1.lst ; gcc -g -o Assignment_1 Assignment_1.o (in directory: /Users/julian/Documents/West_Valley_College_039)
```

[Image of folder content(click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSQ1j.png)

Comment: You seem to have placed another option (`-alh`) between `-o` and the output filename.

Comment: as -g -mfpu=vfpv4 -o %e.s>%e.lst ; gcc -g -o %e %e.o. (is this now correct?)

Comment: Depends on what `%e` expands to. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: %e = file name (firstProgram.s)